# Mongoengine query based on reference field attribute

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have the following Documents

```
Food(Document)
  title = fields.StringField()
  type = fields.StringField()

Recipe(Document)
  title = fields.StringField()
  food = fields.ReferenceField(Food)
```

I would like to get the list of recipes whose food.type == "nonveg"

Can I do something like the following?

```
Recipe.objects.where(food__type="nonveg")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible with a single query, as Reference Field hold only the id of the actual document.
Hence, you need to do, two queries,

1. Which gets all the objects of `Food`, that fall under your `type`. This can be done via the code `foods = Food.objects(type='nonveg')`
2. Now, use the `foods` Objects List to filter the `Recipe` collection as : `Recipe.objects(food__in=foods)`. Also, keep in mind that the `in` operation takes a list, so always pass a list into the filter query, even if you are getting a single instance in `Step 1` using `.get()`

Wrapping up the steps:

```
foods = Food.objects(type="nonveg")
recipes = Recipe.objects(food__in=foods)
```

Answer (score 0):

"type" is a reserved word in mongodb for an operator. So you should use this query : `Recipe.objects(food__type__="nonveg")`

Answer (score -1):

`Recipe.objects(food__type="nonveg")` if you use mongoengine.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I couldn't reproduce the desired result. This will simply throw `OperationFailure: unknown string alias for $type: nonveg`